# Convert string YYMMDD to YYYYMMDD in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, date

I am just wondering is it possible to convert a date string `YYMMDD` to `YYYY-MM-DD`, in example `990102` -> `1999-01-02` in JavaScript?

EDIT from a comment :

If date `200102` is provided it need to output `2012-01-02`, not `1920-01-02`

Comment: You cannot unless you provide a condition on when to use 2000+ and when to use 1900+. Its basically less information in `YY` where the thousands and hundreds are missing. There is no obvious way to determine if `14` is `2014` or `1914`

Comment: So you can take a window like `[1949 - 2050]`. So if `YY>=49` use `1900`+. If `YY<50` use `2000`+ The window can be adjusted per your requirement

Comment: In common use, if YY is greater than a value, it is 1900, if not it is 2000. The value is not constant, depends on the date itself.

Comment: Yes, that `value` should be determined per use-case.

Comment: Didn't you mean 'If date **12**0102 is provided it need to output 2012-01-02, not 1920-01-02'? I don't think so you need something out of range [1970:2038], two last digits are now unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot unless you provide a condition on when to use 2000+ and when to use 1900+. Its basically less information in YY where the thousands and hundreds are missing. There is no obvious way to determine if 14 is 2014 or 1914

So you can take a window like `[1990 - 2089]`. So if `YY>=90` use 1900+. If `YY<90` use 2000+ The window can be adjusted per your requirement

I am not sure if there is any *standard* on what window to use.

[@Kos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399317/kos) says:

> There's a [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html): "When a century is not otherwise specified,
>   values in the range [69,99] shall refer to years 1969 to 1999
>   inclusive, and values in the range [00,68] shall refer to years 2000
>   to 2068 inclusive"

[@RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) says

> ECMA-262 (which is probably more appropriate for javascript) says that
>   any year from 0 to 99 should be treated as 1900 to 1999 ([§20.3.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms)).
>   But of course implementations can do what they want for formats not
>   covered by the spec. In Safari, 1/1/49 is 2049, 1/1/50 is 1950.

```js
//990102 -> 1999-01-02
//using window [1990-2089]
function convertDate(yymmdd) {
  var d = yymmdd; // YYMMDD
  var yy = d.substr(0, 2);
  var mm = d.substr(2, 2);
  var dd = d.substr(4, 2);
  var yyyy = (+yy < 90) ? '20' + yy : '19' + yy;
  return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
}
console.log(convertDate('900102'))
console.log(convertDate('140102'))
console.log(convertDate('890102'))
```

Comment: There's [a POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html): "When a century is not otherwise specified, values in the range [69,99] shall refer to years 1969 to 1999 inclusive, and values in the range [00,68] shall refer to years 2000 to 2068 inclusive"

Comment: ECMA-262 (which is probably more appropriate for javascript) says that any year from 0 to 99 should be treated as 1900 to 1999 ([*§20.3.2.1*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms)). But of course implementations can do what they want for formats not covered by the spec. In Safari, 1/1/49 is 2049, 1/1/50 is 1950.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substring` method.

```js
var date="990102";
console.log("19"+date.substring(0,2)+"-"+date.substring(2,4)+"-"+date.substring(4,6));
```

Comment: Does this support `2000`+?

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, thanks. But in my case it won't work I used 990102 as example. If date will be 200102 provided code won't return 2012-01-02, it will return 1920-01-02

Comment: This information cannot be done with only your information..i need more information.

Comment: Why `200102` returns `2012` ?

Comment: In common use, if YY is greater than a value, it is 1900, if not it is 2000. The value is not constant, depends on the date itself. Not that hard to add the functionnality, no need to update this answer for this

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but here is my solution (in typescript and it worked for me)

```
private convertDate(yymmdd: string) {

    const date: Date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear().toString();

    const d = yymmdd; // YYMMDD
    const yy = d.substr(0, 2);
    const mm = d.substr(2, 2);
    const dd = d.substr(4, 2);
    const yyyy = (+yy < parseInt(year.slice(2, year.length), 10) + 10) ? '20' + yy : '19' + yy;

    return `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;
}
```

It is an adaptation of the answer above except it ensures the gap remains at an incremental (10) distance from the current year to ensure the sustainability